# Opting to use Wifi only while getting location using CoreLocation?

Tags: iphone, gps, wifi, core-location

Is there a way I can ensure that GPS is not used while using CoreLocation? I want to include a "battery save" setting which opts out of using GPS for tracking the phone's location.

Assuming this is possible, is there actually a significant reduction in battery usage if I use Wifi only?

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. However, you can set the `desiredAccuracy` property of your Core Location manager to indirectly do this (the lower the accuracy, the less the system relies on GPS and may be able to entirely rely on WiFi).

The Apple documents also allude to the fact setting a lower accuracy will save power:

> You should assign a value to this property that is appropriate for your usage scenario. In other words, if you need the current location only within a few kilometers, you should not specify kCLLocationAccuracyBest for the accuracy. Determining a location with greater accuracy requires more time and more power.

So you could have a mode that used `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, and a mode that used `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` for your 'low power' mode.

Comment: Okay this means I can't directly opt out of using GPS but it's helpful towards achieving a low power state, which is basically what I want. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've done some testing in iOS 8, and at `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers` the device turns the GPS off. Another way to achieve this is to use significant-change mode instead of GPS. Once you get up to the 3 kilometer range, that is pretty close to equivalent.